# Android Room how to query related table?

Tags: relational-database, android-room

First thing, my data is **POKEMON!!!** enjoy

I need to do this on the database side, filtering and sorting the returned data isn't an option as using Paging...

I'm using Room I have my database working well but I now want to query the pokemonType list in my relation

Given this data class

```
data class PokemonWithTypesAndSpecies @JvmOverloads constructor(

    @Ignore
    var matches : Int = 0,

    @Embedded
    val pokemon: Pokemon,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = Pokemon.POKEMON_ID,
        entity = PokemonType::class,
        entityColumn = PokemonType.TYPE_ID,
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = PokemonTypesJoin::class,
            parentColumn = Pokemon.POKEMON_ID,
            entityColumn = PokemonType.TYPE_ID
        )
    )
    val types: List<PokemonType>,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = Pokemon.POKEMON_ID,
        entity = PokemonSpecies::class,
        entityColumn = PokemonSpecies.SPECIES_ID,
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = PokemonSpeciesJoin::class,
            parentColumn = Pokemon.POKEMON_ID,
            entityColumn = PokemonSpecies.SPECIES_ID
        )
    )
    val species: PokemonSpecies?
)
```

I can get my data with a simple query and even search it

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Pokemon WHERE pokemon_name LIKE :search")
fun searchPokemonWithTypesAndSpecies(search: String): LiveData<List<PokemonWithTypesAndSpecies>>
```

But now what I want is to add filtering on pokemon types which as you can see is a list (which is probably a transaction under the hood) and is in a seperate table, so given a list of string called filters I want to:

- only return pokemon that contain an item in filters
- sort pokemon by both number of matching types and by ID

So I want my tests to look something like this

```
val bulbasaurSpeciesID = 1
val squirtleSpeciesID = 2
val charmanderSpeciesID = 3
val charizardSpeciesID = 4
val pidgeySpeciesID = 5
val moltresSpeciesID = 6

val bulbasaurID = 1
val squirtleID = 2
val charmanderID = 3
val charizardID = 4
val pidgeyID = 5
val moltresID = 6

val grassTypeID = 1
val poisonTypeID = 2
val fireTypeID = 3
val waterTypeID = 4
val flyingTypeID = 5

val emptySearch = "%%"

val allPokemonTypes = listOf(
    "normal",
    "water",
    "fire",
    "grass",
    "electric",
    "ice",
    "fighting",
    "poison",
    "ground",
    "flying",
    "psychic",
    "bug",
    "rock",
    "ghost",
    "dark",
    "dragon",
    "steel",
    "fairy",
    "unknown",
)


@Before
fun createDb() {
    val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
    db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
        context, PokemonRoomDatabase::class.java,
    ).setTransactionExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
        .allowMainThreadQueries()
        .build()
    pokemonDao = db.pokemonDao()
    speciesDao = db.pokemonSpeciesDao()
    speciesJoinDao = db.pokemonSpeciesJoinDao()
    pokemonTypeDao = db.pokemonTypeDao()
    pokemonTypeJoinDao = db.pokemonTypeJoinDao()
}

@After
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun closeDb() {
    db.close()
}

@Test
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun testFiltering() {

    insertPokemonForFilterTest()

    val pokemon =
        pokemonDao.searchAndFilterPokemon(search = emptySearch, filters = allPokemonTypes)
            .getValueBlocking(scope)

    assertThat(pokemon?.size, equalTo(6)) // This fails list size is 9 with the current query

    val pokemonFiltered =
        pokemonDao.searchAndFilterPokemon(search = emptySearch, filters = listOf("fire", "flying"))
            .getValueBlocking(scope)

    assertThat(pokemon?.size, equalTo(4))
    
    assertThat(pokemonFiltered!![0].pokemon.name, equalTo("charizard")) // matches 2 filters and ID is 4
    assertThat(pokemonFiltered!![1].pokemon.name, equalTo("moltres")) // matches 2 filters and ID is 6
    assertThat(pokemonFiltered!![2].pokemon.name, equalTo("charmander")) // matches one filter and ID is 3
    assertThat(pokemonFiltered!![3].pokemon.name, equalTo("pidgey")) // mayches one filter and ID is 5

}

private fun insertPokemonForFilterTest() = runBlocking {
    insertBulbasaur()
    insertSquirtle()
    insertCharmander()
    insertCharizard()
    insertMoltres()
    insertPidgey()
}



private fun insertBulbasaur() = runBlocking {

    val bulbasaur = bulbasaur()
    val grassJoin = PokemonTypesJoin(pokemon_id = bulbasaurID, type_id = grassTypeID)
    val poisonJoin = PokemonTypesJoin(pokemon_id = bulbasaurID, type_id = poisonTypeID)
    val bulbasaurSpeciesJoin =
        PokemonSpeciesJoin(pokemon_id = bulbasaurID, species_id = bulbasaurSpeciesID)

    pokemonDao.insertPokemon(bulbasaur.pokemon)

    speciesDao.insertSpecies(bulbasaur.species!!)
    speciesJoinDao.insertPokemonSpeciesJoin(bulbasaurSpeciesJoin)

    pokemonTypeDao.insertPokemonType(pokemonType = bulbasaur.types[0])
    pokemonTypeDao.insertPokemonType(pokemonType = bulbasaur.types[1])
    pokemonTypeJoinDao.insertPokemonTypeJoin(grassJoin)
    pokemonTypeJoinDao.insertPokemonTypeJoin(poisonJoin)
}

private fun insertSquirtle() = runBlocking {

    val squirtle = squirtle()
    val squirtleSpeciesJoin =
        PokemonSpeciesJoin(pokemon_id = squirtleID, species_id = squirtleSpeciesID)
    val waterJoin = PokemonTypesJoin(pokemon_id = squirtleID, type_id = waterTypeID)

    pokemonDao.insertPokemon(squirtle.pokemon)

    speciesDao.insertSpecies(squirtle.species!!)
    speciesJoinDao.insertPokemonSpeciesJoin(squirtleSpeciesJoin)

    pokemonTypeDao.insertPokemonType(pokemonType = squirtle.types[0])
    pokemonTypeJoinDao.insertPokemonTypeJoin(waterJoin)

}

private fun insertCharmander() = runBlocking {

    val charmander = charmander()
    val fireJoin = PokemonTypesJoin(pokemon_id = charmanderID, type_id = fireTypeID)
    val charmanderSpeciesJoin =
        PokemonSpeciesJoin(pokemon_id = charmanderID, species_id = charmanderSpeciesID)

    pokemonDao.insertPokemon(charmander.pokemon)
    speciesDao.insertSpecies(charmander.species!!)
    speciesJoinDao.insertPokemonSpeciesJoin(charmanderSpeciesJoin)
    pokemonTypeDao.insertPokemonType(pokemonType = charmander.types[0])
    pokemonTypeJoinDao.insertPokemonTypeJoin(fireJoin)
}

private fun insertCharizard() = runBlocking {

    val charizard = charizard()
    val charizardSpeciesJoin =
        PokemonSpeciesJoin(pokemon_id = charizardID, species_id = charizardSpeciesID)

    val fireJoin = PokemonTypesJoin(pokemon_id = charizardID, type_id = fireTypeID)
    val flyingJoin = PokemonTypesJoin(pokemon_id = charizardID, type_id = flyingTypeID)

    pokemonDao.insertPokemon(charizard.pokemon)

    speciesDao.insertSpecies(charizard.species!!)
    speciesJoinDao.insertPokemonSpeciesJoin(charizardSpeciesJoin)

    pokemonTypeDao.insertPokemonType(pokemonType = charizard.types[0])
    pokemonTypeDao.insertPokemonType(pokemonType = charizard.types[1])
    pokemonTypeJoinDao.insertPokemonTypeJoin(fireJoin)
    pokemonTypeJoinDao.insertPokemonTypeJoin(flyingJoin)
}

private fun insertPidgey() = runBlocking {

    val pidgey = pidgey()
    val pidgeySpeciesJoin =
        PokemonSpeciesJoin(pokemon_id = pidgeyID, species_id = pidgeySpeciesID)
    val flyingJoin = PokemonTypesJoin(pokemon_id = pidgeyID, type_id = flyingTypeID)

    pokemonDao.insertPokemon(pidgey.pokemon)

    speciesDao.insertSpecies(pidgey.species!!)
    speciesJoinDao.insertPokemonSpeciesJoin(pidgeySpeciesJoin)

    pokemonTypeDao.insertPokemonType(pokemonType = pidgey.types[0])
    pokemonTypeJoinDao.insertPokemonTypeJoin(flyingJoin)
}

private fun insertMoltres() = runBlocking {

    val moltres = moltres()
    val moltresSpeciesJoin =
        PokemonSpeciesJoin(pokemon_id = moltresID, species_id = moltresSpeciesID)

    val fireJoin = PokemonTypesJoin(pokemon_id = moltresID, type_id = fireTypeID)
    val flyingJoin = PokemonTypesJoin(pokemon_id = moltresID, type_id = flyingTypeID)

    pokemonDao.insertPokemon(moltres.pokemon)

    speciesDao.insertSpecies(moltres.species!!)
    speciesJoinDao.insertPokemonSpeciesJoin(moltresSpeciesJoin)

    pokemonTypeDao.insertPokemonType(pokemonType = moltres.types[0])
    pokemonTypeDao.insertPokemonType(pokemonType = moltres.types[1])
    pokemonTypeJoinDao.insertPokemonTypeJoin(fireJoin)
    pokemonTypeJoinDao.insertPokemonTypeJoin(flyingJoin)
}

fun bulbasaur(): PokemonWithTypesAndSpecies = PokemonWithTypesAndSpecies(
    pokemon = Pokemon(id = bulbasaurID, name = "bulbasaur"),
    species = PokemonSpecies(
        id = bulbasaurSpeciesID,
        species = "Seed pokemon",
        pokedexEntry = "There is a plant seed on its back right from the day this Pokémon is born. The seed slowly grows larger."
    ),
    types = listOf(
        PokemonType(id = poisonTypeID, name = "poison", slot = 1),
        PokemonType(id = grassTypeID, name = "grass", slot = 2)
    )
)

fun squirtle(): PokemonWithTypesAndSpecies = PokemonWithTypesAndSpecies(
    pokemon = Pokemon(id = squirtleID, name = "squirtle"),
    species = PokemonSpecies(
        id = squirtleSpeciesID,
        species = "Turtle pokemon",
        pokedexEntry = "Small shell pokemon"
    ),
    types = listOf(PokemonType(id = waterTypeID, name = "water", slot = 1))
)

fun charmander(): PokemonWithTypesAndSpecies = PokemonWithTypesAndSpecies(
    pokemon = Pokemon(id = charmanderID, name = "charmander"),
    species = PokemonSpecies(
        id = charmanderSpeciesID,
        species = "Fire lizard pokemon",
        pokedexEntry = "If the flame on this pokemon's tail goes out it will die"
    ),
    types = listOf(PokemonType(id = fireTypeID, name = "fire", slot = 1))
)

fun charizard(): PokemonWithTypesAndSpecies = PokemonWithTypesAndSpecies(
    pokemon = Pokemon(id = charizardID, name = "charizard"),
    species = PokemonSpecies(
        id = charizardSpeciesID,
        species = "Fire flying lizard pokemon",
        pokedexEntry = "Spits fire that is hot enough to melt boulders. Known to cause forest fires unintentionally"
    ),
    types = listOf(
        PokemonType(id = fireTypeID, name = "fire", slot = 1),
        PokemonType(id = flyingTypeID, name = "flying", slot = 2)
    )
)

fun moltres(): PokemonWithTypesAndSpecies = PokemonWithTypesAndSpecies(
    pokemon = Pokemon(id = moltresID, name = "moltres"),
    species = PokemonSpecies(
        id = moltresSpeciesID,
        species = "Fire bird pokemon",
        pokedexEntry = "Known as the legendary bird of fire. Every flap of its wings creates a dazzling flash of flames"
    ),
    types = listOf(
        PokemonType(id = fireTypeID, name = "fire", slot = 1),
        PokemonType(id = flyingTypeID, name = "flying", slot = 2)
    )
)

fun pidgey(): PokemonWithTypesAndSpecies = PokemonWithTypesAndSpecies(
    pokemon = Pokemon(id = pidgeyID, name = "pidgey"),
    species = PokemonSpecies(
        id = pidgeySpeciesID,
        species = "Bird pokemon",
        pokedexEntry = "Pidgey is a Flying Pokémon. Among all the Flying Pokémon, it is the gentlest and easiest to capture. A perfect target for the beginning Pokémon Trainer to test his Pokémon's skills."
    ),
    types = listOf(PokemonType(id = flyingTypeID, name = "flying", slot = 1))
)
```

And the query would be

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Pokemon INNER JOIN PokemonType, PokemonTypesJoin ON Pokemon.pokemon_id = PokemonTypesJoin.pokemon_id AND PokemonType.type_id = PokemonTypesJoin.type_id WHERE pokemon_name LIKE :search AND type_name IN (:filters) ORDER BY pokemon_id ASC")
fun searchAndFilterPokemon(search: String, filters: List<String>): LiveData<List<PokemonWithTypesAndSpecies>>
```

I'm guessing this doesn't work because at this point Room hasn't collected the types from the other table and it's probably not even querying a list, I think this part

```
type_name IN (:filters)
```

is checking a column against a list when what I want is a List against a list ‍♂️ but honestly I'm happy to just say I've fallen and can't get up  can anyone help? any help appreciated

Comment: Can you share some input data examples and expected outputs? Your `what I want`-part isn't clear enough without examples.

Comment: @sergiytikhonov I've added the test I've been writing to show input and expected output, thanks for the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I could misuse some columns' names, but try this query:

```
@Query("SELECT pok.id, pok.name FROM Pokemon AS pok
INNER JOIN PokemonTypesJoin AS p_join ON pok.id = p_join.pokemon_id
INNER JOIN PokemonType AS pok_type ON pok_type.id = p_join.type_id
WHERE pok.name LIKE :search AND pok_type.name IN (:filters) 
GROUP BY pok.id, pok.name ORDER BY count(*) DESC, pok.id ASC")
```

Comment: tried to comment but its too long so added an answer just re-affirming your answer many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you compared Room to Cmobilecom-JPA for android? JPA is very good at query relationships. The advantage of using JPA (standard) is obvious, making your code reusable on android, server side java, or swing project.

Comment: thank you, i think this could be achieved using different tech but it has to be Room and it has to be Paging 3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @serglytikhonov my query works and now looks like this

```
@Query("""SELECT * FROM Pokemon 
                 INNER JOIN PokemonTypesJoin 
                 ON Pokemon.pokemon_id = PokemonTypesJoin.pokemon_id 
                 INNER JOIN PokemonType 
                 ON PokemonType.type_id = PokemonTypesJoin.type_id 
                 WHERE pokemon_name LIKE :search AND type_name IN (:filters)
                 GROUP BY Pokemon.pokemon_id, Pokemon.pokemon_name
                 ORDER BY count(*) DESC, pokemon_id ASC""")
fun searchAndFilterPokemon(search: String, filters: List<String>): LiveData<List<PokemonWithTypesAndSpecies>>
```

the main piece being this count(*) and group by many thanks